# Coldfusion: cross ACF11/Lucee 4.5 RestInitApplication() solution

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, lucee

When I use the following code:

```
<cftry>
    <cfif CompareNoCase(request.engine,"Railo") EQ 0>
        <cfset RestInitApplication(request.filepath & "\com\api",local.serviceMapping,false,request.webAdminPassword) />
    <cfelse>
        <cfset RestInitApplication(request.filepath & "\com\api",local.serviceMapping) />
    </cfif>
    <cfcatch>
     </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Adobe Coldfusion throws the following compilation error:

```
Parameter validation error for the RESTINITAPPLICATION function.
The function accepts 1 to 3 parameters.
```

Can anyone suggest a way, I can stop Coldfusion from throwing an error?

If I try and do the following:

```
<cfif CompareNoCase(request.engine,"Railo") EQ 0>
    <cfset RestInitApplication(dirPath=request.filepath & "\com\api",serviceMapping=local.serviceMapping,password=request.webAdminPassword) />
<cfelse>
    <cfset RestInitApplication( dirPath=request.filepath & "\com\api", serviceMapping=local.serviceMapping) />
</cfif>
```

ACF throws a different kind of compilation error:

```
Parameter validation error for the RESTINITAPPLICATION function.
A built-in ColdFusion function cannot accept an assignment statement as a parameter, although it can accept expressions. For example, RESTINITAPPLICATION(d=a*b) is not acceptable.
```

And if I try:

```
<cfif CompareNoCase(request.engine,"Railo") EQ 0>
  <cfset this.webAdminPassword = request.webAdminPassword />
  <cfset RestInitApplication(request.filepath & "\com\api",local.serviceMapping) />
<cfelse>
  <cfset RestInitApplication(request.filepath & "\com\api",local.serviceMapping) />
</cfif>
```

Lucee throws an error telling me that the password is not defined.

**Environment:**

ACF11 on Windows 10

Lucee 4.5 on Windows 2008R2 Server

Comment: Any change if you specify the parameter names? ie `restInitApplication( dirPath=request.filepath & "\com\api"), serviceMapping=local.serviceMapping)`

Comment: This is a good idea, but ACF throws a different kind of compilation error.  Parameter validation error for the RESTINITAPPLICATION function.
A built-in ColdFusion function cannot accept an assignment statement as a parameter, although it can accept expressions. For example, RESTINITAPPLICATION(d=a*b) is not acceptable.

Comment: Sounds similar to what's mentioned in [this entry](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/07/coldfusion-some-built-in-functions.html). The function is messed up, because what you tried should work as the last 2 parameters are optional. Anyway, supplying the "optional" 3rd parameter (structure) seems to make it work: `<cfset restInitApplication( request.filepath & "\com\api", local.serviceMapping, {})>`

Comment: 3 parameters are fine, but 4 is not, in ACF. And I need to provide Lucee with 4, because Password, is the 4th, unfortunately...

Comment: However, I have found a solution which has been tested. It is obscure, but I found it in ACF Rest docs. I will put it up, in a minute, but thanks for your help. And, yes, this function is buggy, but this function, thankfully is not required. And it does not involve using CF/Lucee Administrator.

Comment: There's only 3 parameters in the ACF example above. Did you try it? Though I'm curious to see your solution as well. **(Update)** Might also want to file a bug report too.

Comment: Yes. What I mean is that ACF picks up on the 1st [Railo/Lucee] part of the conditional clause which has 4 params, and throws a wobbly...

Comment: I thought that the conditional would prevent ACF from snooping into the 1st part of the condional, but because it is a Compile Time error, ACF checks every line of code...

Comment: Well that stinks... but makes sense.

Comment: To be honest, I am more annoyed with Lucee for forcing us to use the webAdminPassword. Seems a little unnecessary. Otherwise the original function would have worked fine. It is Lucee at fault, for deviating from the ACF methodology.

Comment: Adam Cameron has done a write up on this, and has complained to the Lucee engineers about this.

Comment: Yeah, that's irritating... In some cases I can see why they'd want to deviate, but not this one. Though Adobe definitely messed up the implementation too, just in a different way :-/

Comment: Agreed. Both need to raise their game on this implementation.

Answer (score 5):

OK. I found a solution which is officially supported. If you look at the Adobe Coldfusion Official Documentation, paragraph entitled "Site-level REST application support", towards the bottom of the page:

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/changes-in-coldfusion/restful-web-services-in-coldfusion.html

It states that you can use the:

```
this.restsettings
```

For nearly all of the:

```
RestInitApplication()
```

Parameters.

I tried the ones it doesn't mention, like:

```
dirPath
password
```

And it works.

So here is the solution:

```
<cfif CompareNoCase(request.engine,"Railo") EQ 0>
  <cfset this.restsettings.dirPath = request.filepath & "\com\api" />
  <cfset this.restsettings.serviceMapping = local.serviceMapping />
  <cfset this.restsettings.password = request.webAdminPassword />
<cfelse>
  <cfset this.restsettings.dirPath = request.filepath & "\com\api" />
  <cfset this.restsettings.serviceMapping = local.serviceMapping />
</cfif>
```

**UPDATE 1**

I have sinced found out that when changes are made to the REST API CFCs, the rest application needs to be refreshed.

This is the purpose of:

```
RestInitApplication()
```

So, I have devised a solution to deal with this issue, that actually simplifies the routine. It seems like the only parameter that **RestInitApplication()** requires is:

```
dirPath
```

Based on this new information, here is the ammendment to my original answer:

```
<cftry>
  <cfif CompareNoCase(request.engine,"Railo") EQ 0>
    <cfset this.restsettings.password = request.webAdminPassword />
  </cfif>
  <cfset restInitApplication(local.dirPath,local.serviceMapping)>
  <cfcatch>
  </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

You could actually remove the second parameter, and replace it with:

```
<cfset this.restsettings.serviceMapping = local.serviceMapping />
```

But, I will leave this decision up to you!

**UPDATE 2:**

After haveing spoken to Sean Corfield, he also suggested another approach, which is really clever.

Using:

```
<cfinclude>
```

As a container for each version of **restInitApplication()**

The code will not throw an error at compile time, even though the parameter count violation still exists. The **cfinclude** acts as a buffer, when placed inside a conditional clause.

So here is a second solution, and, in my opinion, the cleanest one, because, it intialises the REST API, the way it is meant to be done:

```
<cfif CompareNoCase(request.engine,"Railo") EQ 0>
  <cfset restinitdirpath = local.dirPath>
  <cfset restinitservicemapping = local.serviceMapping>
  <cfset restinitdefault = false>
  <cfset restinitpassword = request.webAdminPassword>
  <cfinclude template="includes/structures/rest/railo-rest-init-structure.cfm">
<cfelse>
  <cfset restinitdirpath = local.dirPath>
  <cfset restinitservicemapping = local.serviceMapping>
  <cfinclude template="includes/structures/rest/coldfusion-rest-init-structure.cfm">
</cfif>
```

**railo-rest-init-structure.cfm**

```
<cfoutput>

  <cfparam name="restinitdirpath" default="">
  <cfparam name="restinitservicemapping" default="">
  <cfparam name="restinitdefault" default="false">
  <cfparam name="restinitpassword" default="">

  <cfset restInitApplication(restinitdirpath,restinitservicemapping,restinitdefault,restinitpassword)>

</cfoutput>
```

**coldfusion-rest-init-structure.cfm**

```
<cfoutput>

  <cfparam name="restinitdirpath" default="">
  <cfparam name="restinitservicemapping" default="">

  <cfset restInitApplication(restinitdirpath,restinitservicemapping)>

</cfoutput>
```

Now, I have tested this and it works, and any changes made to your REST API CFCs, subsequently, will get detected each time **restInitApplication()** is hit.

Comment: Good find. Thanks for writing it up :)

Comment: Woops. I better take out my clear text password. Doh!

Comment: .. and for security, change it as well ;-)

Comment: Yes. The password is stored encrypted in the DB, and the salt is in a separate secure DB.

Comment: Can you just use `this.restsettings...` to set all 3 for all environments and just check for existence of `request.webAdminPassword`? You probably don't need to duplicate code (`dirpath` and serviceMapping`).

Comment: `<cfset this.restsettings.password = structKeyExists(request,"webAdminPassword") ? request.webAdminPassword : "">`

Comment: Nice idea @Shawn I have actually decided to stop using the REST API, altogether,  because, using a cross compliant solution is full of problems. For instance because I am no longer using RestInitApplication, the system can no longer refresh itself, when a change is made to the REST CFCs. In fact, when I tried to resolve this, it corrupted the entire Application server. I had to reinstall, ACF. I am only using it to issue refresh tokens, so I will just use a plain component CFC method instead. It maybe that all these issues have been resolved in ACF2016+ & Lucee 5+?

Comment: @Shawn However, I think I have found a solution to the REST API refresh issue, which is vital. I will extend my answer tomorrow, with the final piece of the puzzle l. I am determined to beat this problem...

Comment: Neat! I prefer Update #1 because the logic is in one place, but that's good to know about cfinclude. Didn't realize it could bypass the compile time check!

Comment: @Ageax Yes. Sean, really surprised me, with this gem! Hmmm. Maybe you are right about Update #1, being better. It is certainly shorter! You can also use this.webAdminPassword = '123456', instead of, this.restsettings.password = '123456'. So, there are quite a lot of different approaches, available...

Comment: That is because he is a wizard ;-)